# wordpress showing the wrong featured image in RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

in order to show featured images into my rss feed I added the following code to my function.php

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px;' ) ) . '</div>' . $content;
}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

and it worked, it's showing featured images correctly for most posts but it's showing the wrong ones for some
and I mean an image from a complete different post (like I have a post about depression showing with a featured image from a post about reading) 
I tried to use a plugging instead but I have the same problem no matter what I try
I appreciate your help
thank you very much

Comment: Does the post about depression have a post thumbnail at all? It could be using a fallback image?

Comment: yes it does, and it's showing just fine when I share it on facebook...